# C++ error : terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

Tags: c++, memory-management, runtime-error

I use below code on eclipse and I get an error terminate "called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'  what():  std::bad_alloc".

I have RectInvoice class and Invoice class.

```
class Invoice {
public:

    //...... other functions.....
private:
   string name;
   Mat im;
   int width;
   int height;
   vector<RectInvoice*> rectInvoiceVector; 
};
```

And I use below code on a Invoice's method.

```
        // vect : vector<int> *vect;

        RectInvoice rect(vect,im,x, y, w ,h);
        this->rectInvoiceVector.push_back(&rect);
```

And I want to change eclipse memory in eclipse.ini file. But I dont authorized for this.How can I do this?

Comment: This question is helpful to me also

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935786/c-error-terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stdbad-alloc

Answer (score 27):

The problem in your code is that you can't store the memory address of a local variable (local to a function, for example) in a globlar variable:

```
RectInvoice rect(vect,im,x, y, w ,h);
this->rectInvoiceVector.push_back(&rect);
```

There, `&rect` is a temporary address (stored in the function's activation registry) and will be destroyed when that function end.

The code should create a dynamic variable:

```
RectInvoice *rect =  new RectInvoice(vect,im,x, y, w ,h);
this->rectInvoiceVector.push_back(rect);
```

There you are using a heap address that will not be destroyed in the end of the function's execution.
Tell me if it worked for you.

Cheers

Comment: And don't forget to `delete` every element, if it's no longer needed.

Comment: If you're using dynamic memory allocation, you should be using smart pointers (e.g. std::unique_ptr) to ensure that everything allocated is eventually deleted.

Answer (score 23):

Something throws an exception of type `std::bad_alloc`, indicating that you ran out of memory. This exception is propagated through until `main`, where it "falls off" your program and causes the error message you see.

Since nobody here knows what "RectInvoice", "rectInvoiceVector", "vect", "im" and so on are, we cannot tell you what exactly causes the out-of-memory condition. You didn't even post your real code, because `w h` looks like a syntax error.

Comment: my project has many files, cpp and .h. So I put a small part of it. I think that I should change .ini file. Am I right?

Comment: ok.. thanks for your recommendations. I am newbie on this platform. I am learning :)