# C++ error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

Tags: c++

I wrote the code pasted below to perform the following tasks in the order in which they are stated:

1. Read an input file and count the number of entries in it
2. Create an array of appropriate size (size equal to number of entries)
3. Go back to the beginning of the input file and read it again
4. Store the entries in an array
5. Print out the number of entries in the file and the entries themselves.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    ifstream inFile(argv[1]); //passing arguments to the main function
    int numEntries;

    if(!inFile){
        cout << "file not found" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string entry;
    while (!inFile.eof()){ //counting the number of entries
        getline(inFile,entry);
        ++numEntries;
    }

    const int length = numEntries;  //making an array of appropriate length
    int*arr = new int[length];

    inFile.clear();             //going back to the beginning of the file
    inFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    int i = 0;
    const int size = numEntries;    //making an array to store the entries in the file
    int matrix[size];
    int pos = 0;

    int variable = 0;
    while(pos < size){
        inFile >> variable;
        matrix[pos] = variable;
        ++pos;
    }
    cout<< numEntries << "entries have been read"<< endl; 
    inFile.close();
    for(int i = 0; i < pos; ++i)
        cout << matrix[i] << endl; //printing out the entries
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute the .cpp file I keep getting the error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what(): std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have gathered this has to do with a memory shortage or variables falling out of the main() function, but I can not figure out how to address the problem in this specific situation. If it is relevant, I am working on a Linux computer.

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior. `numEntries` is never initialized. It contains random garbage - likely a very large number.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: If you frequently fail to initialize data, you should switch to Windows/Visual Studio. Visual Studio features static code analysis, that'll catch these sorts of bugs easily.

Comment: Not the problem, but this code has far too much indirection. Get rid of `length` and `size`; just use `numEntries` in both places (after fixing the bug that @IgorTandetnik pointed out). And get rid of `variable` and read directly into `matrix[pos]`. Also, there's no need to `close` the input file. The stream's destructor will do that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: *"The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger."* - That's only if a) your time has no value, and b) you are missing proper tooling.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector` and read the file only once and `push_back` each entry to it? This way, all of the holes in your code will be filled.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This code has 3 holes:

---

First hole: `int numEntries`. Later you do: `++numEntries;`

You increment unspecified value. Not sure if it's UB, but still bad.

---

Second and third hole:

```
const int length = numEntries;
int* arr = new int[length];
```

And

```
const int size = numEntries;
int matrix[size];
```

`numEntries` has unspecified value (first hole). You use it to initialize `length` and `size` - that is Undefined Behaviour. But let's assume it is just some big number - you allocate memory of unspecified size (possibly just very big size), hence the `std::bad_alloc` exception - it means you want to allocate more memory that you have available.

Also, `matrix` is `VLA` of unspecified size, which is both non-standard and Undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

Loss of focus, wasted 30 mins:

```
class Cls1{
    int nV;   //  <------------- nV is un-initialized
    vector<bool> v1;
public:
    Cls1 () {
        v1 = vector<bool> (nV + 1, false);  // <------------------ nV is used
    }
};
```

As you can see nV is un-initialized, but is used below in constructor.

Since the nV took garbage value, different for each run, the program sometimes worked, and other times crashed when the nV garbage value is very high (garbage value)

- Rextester didn't crash, possibly due to some different initialization, https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_gcc
- Apache Netbeans does not show this as warning

  - Having files under Git, you can see changes easily, will find these issue.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

As i was solving the "Book Shop" cses dp problem,I have written the following code..

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>

     using namespace std;

typedef long long in;
const int mod=1000000007;
int main(){
    in n,m;
    cin>>n,m;
    in cost[n];
    in pages[n];
    for(in i=0;i<n;i++)cin>>cost[i];
    for(in i=0;i<n;i++)cin>>pages[i];
    vector<in>dp(m+1,0);
    //cout<<dp[10]<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        //cout<<1<<endl;
        for(int j=m;j>=1;j--){
            
            if(j-cost[i]>=0)dp[j]=(max(dp[j],dp[j-cost[i]]+pages[i]))%mod;
        }
    }
    cout<<dp[m]%mod<<endl;
    
}
```

AND I WAS GETTING THIS..

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Later I FIGURED IT THAT WHILE ASSIGNING n AND m INSTEAD OF `cin>>n>>m;`,

I HAVE WRITTEN `cin>>n,m;`.

SO,I RECCOMEND EVERYONE HAVING THIS KIND OF ISSUE ,PLEASE GO THROW YOUR CODE

ONCE,THERE IS A POSSIBILITY THAT U ARE ALSO COMMITING SAME KIND OF MISTAKE.

```
 HOPE THIS HELPED SOMEONE.

                                                             QUESTIONMARK??
```

Comment: (1) ***Never*** recommend using `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` in a Stack Overflow *answer*. (2) PLEASE STOP SHOUTING. (3) Look at your post(s) after submitting them and correct any formatting errors; this post is a mess.